# Send multidimensional Array via $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I have a multi-dimensional array which I fill via $.each

```
$('.gBook').click(function(){
        var values = [];
        var valueToPush = { }; // or "var valueToPush = new Object();" which is the same
        var i = 0;
        $('td[data-check="true"]').each(function(){
                valueToPush["price"] = $(this).attr("data-price");
                valueToPush["id"] = $(this).attr("data-id");
                values.push(valueToPush);
                i++;
        });

        var arrayToSend = {values};

        $.post( '<?php echo PATH;?>ajax/updateRoom.php',values, function(data){
                if(data != "ERROR"){
                    $('#all-content').html(data).css("overflow-y","auto");
                }else{
                    alert("ERROR");
                }
        });
    });
```

But the outcome is the same for all POST vars:

```
Array (
  [values] => Array (
   [0] => Array ( [price] => 15 [id] => 3380 )
   [1] => Array ( [price] => 15 [id] => 3380 )
   [2] => Array ( [price] => 15 [id] => 3380 )
  ) 
)
```

Where is my mistake? It seems that "push" overrides everytime?

Comment: you should initialize the var `valueToPush` inside the `each` function, you are pushing the same object "pointer" in `values` each time the function is executed (and updating these values)

Comment: You never used your "i" on each

Comment: @Pik_at he doesn't need `i` at all

Comment: That's not a multidimensional array, that's an array of objects.

Comment: i was from something else, you are right i never use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
var valueToPush = { };
```

is outside your loop.

So you:

1. create one object
2. put a reference to it in `valueToPush`
3. put values in it
4. copy the reference to it onto the array
5. go to 3

You only ever have one object,  you just have multiple references to it in the array.

You need to create a new object each time you go around the loop.

```
$('td[data-check="true"]').each(function(){
    var valueToPush = {};
    valueToPush["price"] = $(this).attr("data-price");
```

Comment: I understand that, but however this results in     Array ( [undefined] => )

Comment: Got it, had to use $.post( '<?php echo PATH;?>ajax/updateRoom.php',[b]arrayToSend[/b], function(data){ instead of values...

Answer (score 0):

Your each loop should simply look like this:

```
$('td[data-check="true"]').each(function(){
     values.push({
        price: $(this).attr("data-price"),
        id: $(this).attr("data-id")
     });
 });
```

You need to insert a new object in each iteration. Currently you are inserting references to a single object to into your array.

Comment: also "undefined" as above, starting to believe it's something else?